# How to passing computed with param to props of child component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm a newbie in Vuejs. I'm trying passing computed with param to props of child component but it's error.
This is my code:

```
<FloatingInput
    :type="'text'"
    :name="'username'"
    :error="fieldError('username')"
>
<FloatingInput
    :type="'password'"
    :name="'password'"
    :error="fieldError('password')"
>
```

And in the script:

```
computed: {
    fieldError: {
        get: function () {
            return this.error[field]; // will return false or message error
        },
        set: function (field) {
            this.error[field];
        }
    },          
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computed properties are meant to be pure. This means that computed properties rely solely on the state of the component, and should not have side-effects. This allows Vue to only recalculate computed properties whenever the data they rely on changes. For this reason you can not call a computed property. You must use a method.

Luckily for you, what you want to do is just a key lookup in an object, so you can just use a data attribute and lookup the field.

```
<FloatingInput
  type="text"
  name="username"
  :error="fieldErrors['username']"
>
```

```
data () {
  fieldErrors: {}
},

methods: {
  setFieldError(field, error) {
    this.$set(this.fieldErrors, field, error);
  }
}
```